# laravel DB, get all data form tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome,
I try to combine data from several tables in laravel through "with" I currently have such a thing, and I do not know how to do that with the second call was the main key of Table 1

```
 $profil = Profil::where('ghost', Chat::GHOST_NO);

    $profil->with(['avatar_profils' => function($query) {
        $query->where('id_profil', '=', Session::get('profil')->id);


    }]);

    $profil->with(['msg_profils' => function($query) {
        $query->where('id_profil', '=', ??);


    }]);
```

how to insert id profil from query to "??" in msg_profils ?

Comment: I believe that `$profil->with('msg_profils')` is enough beacause Laravel automatically matches the foreign key.

Comment: so working properly thanks :)

Comment: I write the comment as answer, please set as right

Answer (score 0):

`$profil->with('msg_profils')`, is enough beacause Laravel automatically matches the foreign key.